# 7zip - compress the contents of each folder in a directory

Tags: compression, batch-file, 7-zip

I basically want to compress each file in each folder, delete the original file and leave the folder uncompressed. I don't want to compress the whole folder, only the contents in it.
 That, with 7zip and the LZMA2 algorithm at Ultra compression level.
I'm guessing I'd need a batch file but I'm not very good with that.

Comment: You want to leave a `.7z` file for each file in each folder, or one `.7z` for all the files in that folder?

Comment: I want a .7z file for each file in each folder.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create seperate 7z files from each selected directory with 7zip command line?](http://superuser.com/questions/312652/how-do-i-create-seperate-7z-files-from-each-selected-directory-with-7zip-command)

Comment: I realize the dupe is about Folders and this is about Files, but it and the answers can easily be adapted to do files within a folder.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in batch file:

```
REM Usage: ZipFilesRecursively.bat "C:\My Files"
for /R "%~f1" %%F in (*) do (
    7z a -mx9 "%%~dpnxF.7z" "%%F"
    if exist "%%~dpnxF.7z" del "%%F"
)
```